# How can I put yes and no and their respective percentages on this svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

In this projectI would like to have a Poll like a question and the voter will have a choice of yes or no ,the svg shall display both the results in it but also a color would be assigned to yes and no (see below for my progress)as well as their respective percentage like Instagram's Yes or No Poll.
end result should look something like this:
[image: 1]

Here's the progress I made so far

```html
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="400">
        
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="progress" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
            <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="blue"/>
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      
        <rect id="my-shape" width="300" height="100" fill="url(#progress)" />
      </svg>
    
</body>
<script>
    function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}


setProgress(0.20);

function setProgress(amts)
{
  amts = (amts < 0) ? 0 : (amts > 1) ? 1 : amts;
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amts);
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amts);
}


setProgress(.90);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Nobody will do your work for you, give it a try yourself, do research, learn, try to figure it out and come back when you get stuck.

Comment: There are freelancing services you can hire people from if you need someone to work on this for you. That's not the objective of stackoverflow. You need to ask something more specific, about code you are attempting to write. See the [tour] and [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: @JHeth I did try and I'm Stuck that's why am here I have no idea on how to put 2 colors in an SVG via JS could you provide assistance or point me the right direction ?

Comment: "_I did try_" - It almost always helps if you present your attempt and your research in the question. If you don't know how to do what you want to do, then how close can you actually get? I assume closer than an empty web page - but show us. A little bit of _demonstrated_ work often goes a long way, and will often get you a much more positive response from the community. You can also take that tour already mentioned, and read that "how to ask" guide.

Comment: @andrewjames Ihu heres  how far I reach https://codepen.io/jimmyflasat/pen/RwVKOZq

Comment: Present your attempt and your research in the question (as I mentioned in my comment). Also, if you had read the "how to ask" page you would have seen an explanation of this exact point: "_...but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS._". If you write enough bad questions, you run the risk of being banned from asking any questions at all. I am trying to help you avoid that situation.

Comment: @andrewjames Understood and I have done so all I'm missing is the text "Yes" "No" and their percentages

Comment: Thank you - that is a big step in the right direction. You can (and should) also edit the text of your question so it matches the actual problem you are facing, instead of being a list of requirements. (In the meantime, I have voted to re-open the question. If enough people vote to re-open, then people will be able to post answers again. But there are no guarantees that anyone will actually do so.)

Comment: @andrewjames okay will do thanks alot for the help and advice

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Using Flex in addition to `<p>` tags outside of SVG, something like below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <svg width="400" height="400">
        
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="progress" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
            <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="blue"/>
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      
        <rect id="my-shape" width="300" height="100" fill="url(#progress)" />
      </svg>
  <p class="poll__yes">Yes <br /> <span>80%</span></p>
  <p class="poll__no">No <br /> <span>20%</span></p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.poll__yes {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.poll__no {
  position: absolute;
  right: 19.7em ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function setProgress(amts)
{
  amts = (amts < 0) ? 0 : (amts > 1) ? 1 : amts;
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amts);
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amts);
}

setProgress(.80);
```

I made few tweaks to your code to get you started and take this further

2. You can also use `<svg><text>` [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp) and control it via JS

Hope these get you started to where you want to go, position needs to be controlled based on your progress. Best of Luck

Output:
[image]